# unable to get RGraph (Canvas) to work on Internet Explorer 6 to 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, rgraph

I am displaying a simple bar chart using RGraph. Found here:[RGraph](http://www.rgraph.net/docs/msie.html)

Here is my code: `var vprogress = new RGRAPH.VProgress('vc',200,500); 
                  vprogress.draw()`

I also have the following line in my index.hmtl :

```
<!--[if IE]><script src="/excanvas/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

I also have this in my index.html

```
<canvas id="vc" width="100px" height="800px">[No Canvas Support]</canvas>
```

I am unable to view the graph in either IE 6 and 8, I haven't been able to test in 7.

I am getting line errors in excanvas.js and nothing displays.

The graphs work perfectly in Chrome and Firefox.

I must also mention that my javascript is done in a Jquery Ajax function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone interested.

I found that the problem was that I included 'px' in the height and the width. Remove these for it to function correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For IE, I would also add that you must wrap your Graph code in a window.onload function:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var vprogress = new RGRAPH.VProgress('vc',200,500); 
  vprogress.draw();
}
```